# Regex not able to parse last group

Tags: c#, regex

This is the test. I expect the last group to be `".png"`, but this pattern returns `""` instead.

```
var inputStr = @"C:\path\to\dir\[yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm].png";
var pattern = @"(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var match = regex.Match(inputStr);

var thirdGroupValue = match.Groups[3].Value;
// ✓ EXPECTED: ".png"
// ✗ CURRENT: ""
```

The 1st and 2nd groups work fine.

Comment: That is because of the `?` in the last group. Your pattern there is take zero or more letters and be lazy (as in return the first part that matches). That part is just an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you made the `*` in Group 3 lazy:

```
(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?)
                 ^
                here
```

This means it will match as little as possible. What's the least `.*` can match? An empty string!

You can learn more about lazy vs greedy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

You can fix this either by removing `?`, making it greedy, or put a `$` at the end, telling it to match until the end of the string:

```
(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*)
```

or

```
(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?)$
```

Comment: Oh I get it. This was very informative, specially this part: `What's the least .* can match? An empty string!` <= never thought of it this way.